# I can't use the control drag function to hook up a button to action in .h when using storyboard with more than one view controller

Tags: xcode, controls, storyboard, drag

Why can't I use the control drag function to hook up a button to action in .h when using storyboard with more than one view controller? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks a lot on beforehand!

Anton